# TProxy IPv6 not sending connections

Tags: ipv6

I'm trying to capture connections using tproxy, but I'm unable to receive IPv6 TCP connections. IPV4 TCP and both UDP work properly. TCP v4 and v6 are both received from the same accept call. I'm on Android 9.

```
PORT=2080
MARK=2080

iptables -t $TABLE -A $CHAIN -p tcp -j TPROXY --on-port $PORT --tproxy-mark $MARK
iptables -t $TABLE -A $CHAIN -p udp -j TPROXY --on-port $PORT --tproxy-mark $MARK

ip rule add fwmark $MARK lookup 100
ip route add local default dev lo table 100

ip6tables -t $TABLE -A $CHAIN -j LOG --log-prefix='[iptables] '
ip6tables -t $TABLE -A $CHAIN -p tcp -j TPROXY --on-port $PORT --tproxy-mark $MARK
ip6tables -t $TABLE -A $CHAIN -p udp -j TPROXY --on-port $PORT --tproxy-mark $MARK

ip -6 rule add fwmark $MARK lookup 100
ip -6 route add local default dev lo table 100
```

The log output shows ICMP packets and TCP packets with IPv6 and IPv4 addresses, but only IPv4 gets accepted on the listener.

Occasionally something connects from WSL on my laptop, but nothing else connects over ipv6 and browser tests such as https://ipv6-test.com/ say ipv6 failed.

Running the command `curl google.com` in WSL hangs until I press ctrl+c, at which point the accept call returns the now useless socket.

Comment: Cross-posted from Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/q/1106053/252799

Comment: Cross-posted to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/710747/180315

Comment: Please refer to Unix & Linux for more information.